# Scroll ScrollView to item of nested ListView

Tags: android, user-interface, android-listview, android-scrollview

I am working on Receipt-App. One Activity manages the different ingredients in a LinearLayout:

- Some text about the starter
- ListView of starter ingredients
- Some text about the main dish
- ListView of main dish ingredients
- ...

The user can add any number of ingredients to the different lists. Thus the number of list items and the size of the complete view/activity is not limited. Because of this the complete `LinearLayout` is nested in a `ScrollView`.

Of course having a vertical scrolling `ListView` inside a vertical scrolling `ScrollView` is not a good idea. But I am using a custom `ListView` sub-class that overrides `onMeasure(...)` and expends the size of the `ListView` to cover all items. This `CustomListView` does not scroll and thus does not conflict with the `ScrollView`. This works without any problem.

Assume the `ScrollView` is scrolled to the top and the user adds a new ingredient that will be placed in the middle of the main dish list. This list is currently of screen.

**How can I scroll the `ScrollView` to show the added ingredient list item?**

Of course I know the `scrollBy(x, y)` and `scrollTo(x, y)` methodes the `ScrollView` provides. But how do I get the necessary values for y (scolling in x direction not necessary)?

I would need a way to get the coordinates of the view of the list item and translate them to coordinates within the `ScrollView`. But how do I get the view of the list item in the first place?

Comment: did you ever think of using ExpandableListView, with starter and main as group names and corresponding dishes as their children?

Comment: Yes, but "starter" and "main" are not just plain texts that could be used as group names but some "complex" content like text, images, slider to adjust the number of guests, etc.

Comment: just disable the parent scroll when you touch on listview and disble the listview scroll when u touch scrollview.

Comment: @DevCarlsberg Sorry but I do not see how this is related to the question. What has touch to do with finding a the row view scrolling to it programmatically?